# get Timezone from Date object - Java

Tags: java, java.util.date

Can we get timezone details from java.util.Date object? I need to print the birthdate without affecting the timezone. Suppose someone has a birthdate on "12-15-1998 11:45:50 AM" with timezone America/Los_Angeles. Suppose I want to print birthdate in India. Then I don't want time zone in India change the birthdate to "12-16-1998 12:15:50 PM"?  At the end, I just want to print "12-15-1998". thanks in advance.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting. These issues have been addressed many hundreds, if not thousands, of times already on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `java.util.Date` does not have a time zone associated with it. Its `toString()` method may make it appear to have a time zone, but it doesn't. The time zone provided by `toString()` is the system default time zone.

A `Calendar` does have a time zone associated with it. And that appears to be what you are trying to do.

Comment: that's what I am looking for. perfect....!!!

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.